# Is it possible to you reduce the surface retention of water on a stainless steel surface.

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, adhesion

The surface is mechanically brushed.

I have already considered hydrophobic surface treatment. Are there any other methods to reduce the adhesion forces between water molecules to the surface.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, because there is no way to alter the metal atoms in the steel to ignore water molecules any more or less than they already do.

Since the water is in contact with the surface of the metal, any means you would wish to employ to render that surface less attractive to water molecules will necessarily involve covering the metal with something different.

Note also that there is nothing you could possibly put into the water itself which would increase the adhesion forces between adjacent water molecules, so as to reduce their affinity for metal contact.

In some cases, the wettability of a metal surface can be changed by growing an oxide film on that surface- but for stainless steel, the chrome and nickel in the steel's surface  already have an oxide layer adsorbed onto them (which is the reason why the steel is corrosion-resistant in the first place).

Comment: Thank you for your response Niels, Would temperature variation ( heating the water) affect the adhesion of the water molecules to the adjacent stainless steel plate, that I should see a significant change in the behaviors of the water molecules regarding surface retention?

Comment: as water heats up, its surface tension goes down. this is why hot water does a better job of washing clothes but it also means that the hot water will wet the stainless even better than it would at room temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your application allows it, but incline or shape modification can help. If water is undesirable because of corrosion, [cathodic protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathodic_protection) can be used.